# Не работает Emmet в sass-файлах в редакторе Sublime Text 3

Tags: sass, sublime-text-3, emmet

во такой запрос: `h$[title=item$]{Header $}*3`

выводит вот это:

```
height: $[title=item $]{Header  $}Header 1
height: $[title=item $]{Header  $}Header 2
height: $[title=item $]{Header  $}Header 3
```

а нужно вот это:

```
<h1 title="item1">Header 1</h1>
<h2 title="item2">Header 2</h2>
<h3 title="item3">Header 3</h3>
```

Ruby установлен,  Ruby Gem установлен, a редактируемом файле .sass выставлен синтаксис Sass

Comment: что тут происходит???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь писать html код в файле sass, когда sass - это предпроцессоры css.

Comment: А как будет правильно?